# Rails Access Deined when uploading image on Heroku to Amazon s3 with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

i try to upload image using amazon S3, but i have this error:

```
AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied)
```

i used paperclip configuration:

```
    config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

and i set a permission like this

[image]

thank you !

EDIT:

I created another bucket and it works, but now i have this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass):
```

Comment: Have you set your `ENV` vars in the Heroku config?

Comment: Yes I set AWS configuration vars

Answer (score 1):

production.rb/development.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_protocol => 'http',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

While Creating a bucket Select region as US-Standard and use above config.
Try this it worked for me.Hopefully would work for you too.